# What's the meaning of android:progressBarStyle attribute in ProgressBar?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-styles

I've been looking through the documentation for `ProgressBar` class and found these attributes:

- android:progressBarStyle
- android:progressBarStyleHorizontal
- android:progressBarStyleLarge
- android:progressBarStyleSmall

These four parameters are supposed to be a reference to some style as I take it. So the question is, what are these for? Style for the progress bar is set via android:style attribute and a reference to the global style attributes.

Documentation doesn't say anything helpful, searched the Web, found nothing.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The four attributes that you mention can be applied to a `ProgressBar`'s style like so:

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

The style constant `android:progressBarStyleHorizontal` is your typical incremental progress bar:

[image]

While the other three are varying sizes of the same circular progress bar:

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
```

[image]

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
```

[image]

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
```

[image]

**Update:**

According to adamp's comments:

> These are attributes of the theme that
>   point at themed styles you can use for
>   progress indicators...They are not attributes for ProgressBar itself.

Comment: The documentation means what it says, it's just not terribly verbose about it. ;) These are attributes of the theme that point at themed styles you can use for progress indicators. Their exact values can change from theme to theme, it's just a layer of indirection. This answer is correct. Set the style attribute to one of these. They are not attributes for ProgressBar itself.

Comment: @adamp: Thanks for the clarification, I'll update my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: So the answer is basically "They are not attributes for ProgressBar itself". Yes, I know how to set the style of the progress bar. :) I was only wondering, what changes if you change the attributes, but if these attributes aren't actually attributes, everything becomes clear. P.S. Some parts of Android documentation really suck.

Comment: They *are* attributes, but they're attributes for themes, not for the ProgressBar widget. The "?android:attr/foo" syntax with the "?" sigil means, "resolve the resource contained in this theme attribute within the current theme."

Comment: I designed and custom view and using it as an lib component. Here I'm using progress bar but not able to change style="?android:attribute for same. It showing same progress bar I checked same  with some other parameter to make sure I'm using same. Any suggestion !!!

Answer (score 2):

In case if someone is looking for full block of code

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/ProgressBar2"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The confusing part is that normally, you can define a default style for a widget (e.g. a button) like this:

```xml
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored</item>
```

All buttons will then by default have this style applied.

One would think that the progressBarStyle attribute would do the same for ProgressBar if doing this:

```xml
<item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar</item>
```

But that is not the case, since `progressBarStyle` belongs to the `ActionBar` styleable.

Comment: When you're using AppCompat you're supposed to use `progressBarStyle` instead of `android:progressBarStyle`. That's true for all widgets except `android:textViewStyle`. Agreed that it's confusing.

Comment: Not true, you only need to do so for attributes that belong to a `AppCompat...` widget (e.g. `AppCompatEditText`, `AppCompatImageView`, etc.). There's no `AppCompatProgressBar`, so defining `progressBarStyle` without the Android prefix has no effect.

Comment: Damn, you're right, forgot about that. And it's not even wired to AppCompat's `progressBarStyle`. According to `ProgressBar` source code it should pick up `android:progressBarStyle` by default. Why don't you investigate why that doesn't work in your case? Stack Overflow is not a forum and your post doesn't really answer the question.