# how to make circular progresbar with progress status in android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to show the progress bar like below image along with progress status, can any body give me the solution for this

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create circular progress bar(pie chart) like indicator - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458476/how-to-create-circular-progress-barpie-chart-like-indicator-android)