# How to change the circular progress bar Spinner Speed?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, countdowntimer

As mentioned ([How To Make Circle Custom Progress Bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688117/how-to-make-circle-custom-progress-bar-in-android)I) am using https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel lib in my project. I am developing the game app which has different set of levels. I use circular progress bar as timer. I want to change the rotating speed once the user get high score.

Please check the Image sample here. ([How to create circular progress bar(pie chart) like indicator - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458476/how-to-create-circular-progress-barpie-chart-like-indicator-android)).
I didn't get proper solution to fix time limit as well as change time limit using progress bar.

Please help to change the Circular progress bar Spinner speed. Please help on it.

Comment: go throw https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boopathy.raja.tutorial may be pie chart example is help full for you.

Comment: @bhaveshkaila thanks for your reply.. I can set circular progress bar but I can't control the wheel spinner speed. Is it possible?

Comment: This post is too old. Still if needed, try https://github.com/Shah-Sahab/CircularProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `setSpinSpeed` method
or set value of `pwSpinSpeed` attribute in layout file