# How can I design a custom progress bar?

Tags: android, android-edittext, progress-bar

I want to design an android app. I get values in `EditText`, then I put those values into `progressbar`
so that it can show strength like wifi style.
For example:
[How to create circular progress bar(pie chart) like indicator - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458476/how-to-create-circular-progress-barpie-chart-like-indicator-android)

Comment: There are many duplicate question and Q&As.

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the links.

1 ] https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar

2 ] https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar

3 ] https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar

4 ] https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

5 ] https://github.com/FireZenk/FireZenk-s-ProgressBar

Comment: Thank you.but I still don't know how to start?For Example:https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar It's only show how to design an CircularProgressBar,not show how put values into progressbar.Sorry,I am new Android programmer,I really don't know how to design a beautifully UI.

Comment: As it stands now, this is a link-only answer. Please update your post to include relevant information from the references.